# Topology of a 3,10 Torus Knot

Tags: general-topology

A 3,10 torus knot is a knot that loops around a 2-torus (or doughnut) three times with one continuously strand of string that winds through the center hole ten times.  Is this 3,10 torus considered topologically equivalent to a 2-torus?

Comment: In the phrase "3,10 torus knot", the "3,10" modifies the noun phrase "torus knot". There is no such thing as a "3,10 torus", so your question does not really make any sense. If I have misunderstood something, please edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: @MarkDominus Perhaps OP is referring to the solid creating by turning the "strings" in a $(p,q)$-knot into three-dimensional tubes with nonzero volume, [as in the Wikipedia illustration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TorusKnot3D.png)?

Comment: That would be a sensible question! I wonder if that is what is being asked, and I hope OP will clear things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the interpretation given by anon in the comments, yes, what you have is a knotted torus, but a torus all the same (that is, homeomorphic to a torus). Think about slicing through it, then unravelling it from the torus it loops around, giving you a cylinder, then gluing it back together along the slice: that gives you a torus, so the original was just a torus, albeit embedded in 3-space in an amusing way.